# Black make function arguments formatting without new lines around barackets

Tags: python, static-analysis, code-formatting, python-black, black-code-formatter

I'd like to format function argumetns in a way similar to the PyCharm default formatting - see image. Meaning no new line after '(' and before `)` so it does NOT look like in the second image. It looks cleaner to me when function name is more visible.

I want this:

[image]

I do NOT want this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Black is a *highly opinionated* formatter with the stated goal of making diffs shorter and consistent.

[This](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style/current_style.html) is what you get.

The *only* thing you can configure for Black, at the time of writing, is the line length.